# Unable to use libcurl with cffi on Windows 10

Tags: windows, common-lisp, msys2, cffi

I am playing with the CFFI [tutorial](https://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/Tutorial_002dLoading.html#Tutorial_002dLoading) on Windows 10 and have installed the `libcurl-devel` package using msys2. I found a file `libcurl.dll.a` in the directory `c:\msys2\usr\lib\` and added this directory to `*foreign-library-directories*` using:

```
(pushnew #P"c:/msys64/usr/lib/" *foreign-library-directories*
         :test #'equal)
```

But if I try `(use-foreign-library libcurl)` I get the following error:

```
Unable to load foreign library (LIBCURL).
  Error opening shared object "libcurl.dll"
```

What am I missing? I tried to point to `libcurl.dll.a` directly but the error stays the same:

```
(define-foreign-library libcurl
      (:darwin (:or "libcurl.3.dylib" "libcurl.dylib"))
      (:unix (:or "libcurl.so.3" "libcurl.so"))
      (t "libcurl.dll.a"))
```

Here is the complete code as given in the tutorial:

```
(asdf:load-system :cffi)

 ;;; Nothing special about the "CFFI-USER" package.  We're just
 ;;; using it as a substitute for your own CL package.
(defpackage :cffi-user
  (:use :common-lisp :cffi))

(in-package :cffi-user)

(pushnew #P"c:/msys64/usr/lib/" *foreign-library-directories*
         :test #'equal)

(define-foreign-library libcurl
  (:darwin (:or "libcurl.3.dylib" "libcurl.dylib"))
  (:unix (:or "libcurl.so.3" "libcurl.so"))
  (t (:default "libcurl")))

(use-foreign-library libcurl)
```

**EDIT**

I am using SBCL 1.4.16 from the portacle package.

**EDIT 2**

Just for the sake of completeness. If I change `define-foreign-library` to

```
(define-foreign-library libcurl
  (:darwin (:or "libcurl.3.dylib" "libcurl.dylib"))
  (:unix (:or "libcurl.so.3" "libcurl.so"))
  (t "libcurl.dll.a"))
```

the errors changes:

```
Unable to load foreign library (LIBCURL).
  Error opening shared object "c:\\msys64\\usr\\lib\\libcurl.dll.a":
 %1 ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung.
```

As far as I understand at least the file is found but seems not to be in the right format. I didn't find any further information about the difference between dynamic (`.dll`) and static (`.dll.a`) files with respect to cffi and don't have the resources at the moment to further investigate this.

Comment: which 64bit Lisp were you using?

Comment: I'd suspect it wants the `.dll` not `.a` … ?

Comment: Well, that's the most obvious conclusion. I will see when I find the time to struggle with Windows again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `use-foreign-library`, try loading `load-foreign-library`.  It is lower level code, but it will allow you to experiment with files and paths.

Also use cygcheck to figure out what `libcurl.dll` depends on.  Then make sure you have the components installed, and that they are in `PATH`.

Finally, check where libcurl.dll lives in your MSYS2.  On my system it is in `/c/msys64/mingw64/bin/libcurl-4.dll`

Comment: If I use `(load-foreign-library #P"c:/msys64/usr/lib/libcurl.dll.a")` I still get the same error. I have to see if I really want to dig deeper into the difference between `.dll` and `.dll.a` files and why mysys2 installs the later etc.

Comment: On my system, I have libcurl in `/c/msys64/mingw64/bin/libcurl-4.dll`.  Might be worth a try.

Comment: That seems to work! Due to my limited knowledge, I was expecting a library not in a `bin` directory and was looking in the wrong places all the time. I will gladly accept this as an answer if you post it as one.

Comment: I clarified my original post to look for libcurl in the `bin` subdirectory